# Can Azure Web App receive email SMTP, and send email (SendGrid)?

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, sendgrid

Presently I use VisualBasic .NET web app (with SendGrid for email) running on my Azure server VM.  I receives SMTP email from public Internet directly to the VM ok.  It send email using SendGrid addon ok.

Will this all work if I switch to Azure Web App (formerly Web Site)?

Should my web app code work as-is without modification, even the SendGrid calls?

Comment: What is preventing you from trying it out yourself? Why do you need to ask this here? Stack Overflow is for solving specific programming problems, not informing you of problems you may face on a hosting platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outgoing email using SendGrid will not be a problem at all.  Using it on App Service is common and you probably don't need to change any code at all.

Inbound may require changes depending on what you're doing.  Are you simply polling a mailbox somewhere else and then doing something with the messages?  If so, you could convert that to a scheduled WebJob poll at a specific interval and act on incoming messages.

If you're running an SMTP server on your VM to receive mail, then that's something you cannot easily replicate on App Service.